# Issue tracking: how I can reproduce the column called comment?

Tags: column, issue-tracking, comments

The issue tracking list has got a 'comment' that is very unique. It is an empty box that can host editing by different people that it saves beneath one after the other with time and date and author.

If I wanted to have this field in another list, how can I reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a multi line of text and use option  "Append Changes to existing text"